# How to get Yahoo contact list integration in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to get user's all yahoo contact list in app. Simply user should login with yahoo mail id then user able to get all his yahoo contact list in json response.

Comment: [Yahoo contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/), maybe?

Comment: @Omar:I have already seen there.